# Анимация числа (от 1 до заданного) при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок с числом 1000, при загрузке страницы нужно, чтобы происходила анимация от 1 до 1000 (любого другого числа).

Comment: Ну раз нужно - сделайте. Попытайтесь, и когда не получится что-то, тогда прикрепите код с попыткой. И тогда, возможно, ответят.

Comment: Вопрос супер... `...анимация от 1 до 1000 (любого другого числа)`, как это понять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы изменить цифру предел которой происходит анимация - то изменяем  `data-num` с 1000 до нужной ...

```js
var time = 4;
$('div').each(function() {
  var i = 1,
    num = $(this).data('num'),
    step = 1000 * time / num,
    that = $(this),
    int = setInterval(function() {
      if (i <= num) {
        that.html(i);
      } else {
        clearInterval(int);
      }
      i++;
    }, step);
});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-num="1000"></div>
```

Comment: подятгивать Jquery, для такой задачи - не серьйозно.

Comment: @Дмытрык  почему ? эту библиотеку можно же использовать не только для этого , для многого

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский спасибо за пример. Не совсем правильно задал вопрос, но Ваш ответ решает мой вопрос.

Нашел библиотеку на ванилле https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/

Comment: А еще можно скриптом сгенерировать `<div>`, в котором колонкой будут написаны числа от 1 до 1000, спозиционировать абсолютно, добавить `transition-duration:1s`, запихать его в другой `<div>`, ограниченный по высоте и с `overflow:hidden`, и по наведению мышки/загрузке/и т.п. менять диву с числами `position` с `top:0` на `top:calc(100%  - %высота_родительского_дива%)`. Будет плавненькое такое пробегание по всем числам= )